# "Windows" key as part of a shortcut key

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

I very often open a console window while doing my development.  Usually <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> cmd -> enter.  However, Windows also lets you add a shortcut key to any shortcut ... but when I try to add <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to make the shortcut for my favorite-sized/shaped/buffered console appear, it uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead (already used in various editors and other apps...no go.)

Is there any way to use the windows key as part of a shortcut key combo?

*(This would be with Windows XP)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for this sort of thing.

And while you are at it. Use [console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) for a much improved command console experience.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the Tooltip (Click the ? and then the label), it says it automatically uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> with the intent of picking the final character and no other modifiers -- I assume to avoid overlap with existing shortcut keys. So, no, I don't think you can assign the Windows key in that manner. There may be some third-party tools (e.g. [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)) that lets you do so, though.

Answer (score 1):

Also see Kana's SendKey executable. [Site](https://kanasolution.com/products/kana-sendkey/)

You'll see LWIN or RWIN even allows you to choose the left or right WinKey. It's pretty versatile when scripting... and as a bonus it doesn't require installation.

Here's the readme contents:

```
___________
DESCRIPTION:

Kana SendKey is a command line program which can be used
to send a system wide hotkey.

__________
HOW TO USE:

1. Run it with several parameters attached into the
   command line. For information about the parameters,
   see the Parameter section below.

2. You can also create a shortcut and assign the parameters
   on shortcut.

______
SYNTAX:

KanaKey [parameter1] [parameter2] ...

Example:
To send system wide CTRL+ALT+O, use:
KanaKey CTRL ALT O

Note: If no parameter is given, no action is performed.

__________
PARAMETERS:

  CTRLBREAK   = Control+Break
  BACKSPACE   = Backspace key
  TAB         = Tab key
  CLEAR       = Clear key
  RETURN      = Enter key
  SHIFT       = Shift key
  CTRL        = Ctrl Key
  ALT         = Alt key
  PAUSE       = Pause key
  CAPS        = Caps Lock key
  ESC         = Esc key
  SPACE       = Space key
  PAGEUP      = Page Up key
  PAGEDOWN    = Page Dn key
  END         = End key
  HOME        = Home key
  LEFT        = Left Arrow key
  UPARROW     = Up Arrow key
  RIGHTARROW  = Right Arrow key
  DOWNARROW   = Down Arrow key
  PRINTSCR    = Prnt Scrn key
  INSERT      = Insert Key
  DEL         = Delete Key
  LWIN        = Left Win key
  RWIN        = Right Win key
  NUM0        = Numeric 0 key
  NUM1        = Numeric 1 key
  NUM2        = Numeric 2 key
  NUM3        = Numeric 3 key
  NUM4        = Numeric 4 key
  NUM5        = Numeric 5 key
  NUM6        = Numeric 6 key
  NUM7        = Numeric 7 key
  NUM8        = Numeric 8 key
  NUM9        = Numeric 9 key
  MULTIPLY    = * key on numeric key pad
  ADD         = + key on numeric key pad
  SUBTRACT    = - key on numeric key pad
  DECIMAL     = . key on numeric key pad
  DIVIDE      = / key on numeric key pad
  F1          = F1 key
  F2          = F2 key
  F3          = F3 key
  F4          = F4 key
  F5          = F5 key
  F6          = F6 key
  F7          = F7 key
  F8          = F8 key
  F9          = F9 key
  F10         = F10 key
  F11         = F11 key
  F12         = F12 key
  F13         = F13 key
  F14         = F14 key
  F15         = F15 key
  F16         = F16 key
  F17         = F17 key
  F18         = F18 key
  F19         = F19 key
  F20         = F20 key
  F21         = F21 key
  F22         = F22 key
  F23         = F23 key
  F24         = F24 key
  NUMLOCK     = Num Lock key
  SCROLLLOCK  = Scroll Lock key
```